# Raspberry serial port driver issue - trying to connect to Solar Charge controller

Tags: raspberry-pi

I would like to ask you for your help. This is my first post in stackoverflow so I hope community can help me:-)

Description of the issue:

I have Solar Charge Controller Epever Tracer which is capable of communicating via RS485. Next to it I have Raspberry Pi which I would like to use to read the stats from SCC. These two devices are connected via USB to serial cable (Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e2:1411 Exar Corp. XR21B1411
).

I have Node-Red server installed in Pi and have a prepared dashboard according this project:
https://github.com/AdamWelchUK/NodeRedEPEverDashboard

This Node-Red flow uses the Modbus (node-red-contrib-modbus extension) nodes which are set to proper serial port but it doesn't receive any data (although the node says "connected")

I did some extensive research before asking this question and I was actually able to find out that the problem is actually within the Serial driver in Raspberry. Currently it is set as this:

`ls -l /dev/tty*`

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166,  0 Jun  8 12:54 /dev/ttyACM0`

Apparently in order to work it has to be this:

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166,  0 Jun  8 12:54 /dev/ttyUSB0`

So I found instruction how to switch COM driver in here: https://github.com/kasbert/epsolar-tracer

*Compile and install the common usb serial driver module*

```
# make
# insmod ./xr_usb_serial_common.ko
```

*Ensure that thecdc-acm module is not loaded (assumig that it is not needed)*

```
# echo blacklist cdc-acm > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc-acm.conf 
# update-initramfs -u
```

I know that I should somehow compile the driver first using *make* command, but I have no idea how to do so. *Insmod* is giving me permission denied error. I am completely lost at this moment

What I have tried:

- I connected the cable into Windows PC with native software which comes with SCC and it is working properly, so cable seems to be OK
- I tried to at least do the blacklist thing but also this: `-bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc-acm.conf: Permission denied`

I am pretty new to Linux so any help would be highly appreciated. I tried to do this post as short as possible so if you need any more information I will be happy to provide...

Thank you in advance for your help:-)

EDIT: I also try to use all commands with "sudo". Still no luck.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I am trying to program the dashboard in Node-Red... But if this isn't the right place to ask then I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo to execute the command:

```
sudo insmod ./xr_usb_serial_common.ko
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have tried all commands with sudo as well (sorry I forgot to mention in my question). There is problem, that I do not have the ./xr_usb_serial_common.ko file at all. It has to be somehow compiled first using the "make" command. (That is the tricky part for me)...

Comment: Try using the instructions and files [here](https://github.com/dernasherbrezon/epever-tracer-influxdb/tree/master/xr_usb_serial_common)